# How to do SSO from your corporate AD or LDAP directory and restricts access for each user to a designated user folder in a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-sign-on

I came across this question in my AWS study and wondering if anyone can enlighten me with more on my question:

> Your fortune 500 company has under taken a TCO analysis evaluating the
>   use of Amazon S3 versus acquiring more hardware The outcome was that
>   all employees would be granted access to use Amazon S3 for storage of
>   their personal documents. Which of the following will you need to
>   consider so you can set up a solution that incorporates single sign-on
>   from your corporate AD or LDAP directory and restricts access for each
>   user to a designated user folder in a bucket? (Choose 3 Answers)

```
A. Setting up a federation proxy or identity provider
B. Using AWS Security Token Service to generate temporary tokens
C. Tagging each folder in the bucket
D. Configuring IAM role
E. Setting up a matching IAM user for every user in your corporate directory that needs access to a folder in the bucket
```

The answers from the source say ABD, what I wonder is would it be needed to tag each folder in the bucket (i.e. via use of the '**username**' policy variable) to associate the folder to its user?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to tag each folder. You can simply base your matching logic on folder/path prefixes.

Suppose that you have 2 "*folders*" (there are no folders in S3 since it is a flat storage) in `my-bucket` s3 bucket.

```
s3://my-bucket/user1
S3://my-bucket/user2
```

You can match on `user1` and `user2` if you wish to in your IAM role eg.

```
Role1 - resource: s3://my-bucket/user1/*
```

and

```
Role2 - resource: s3://my-bucket/user2/*
```

That being said, you can implement some tagging structure for your buckets/folders and do the matching based on tags but that is simply unnecessary in this scenario.